# select top 1 record for each record on 1 table

Tags: sql

I have problems on query. I need the result that shows top 1 for each records from the table that has same id. Here is the Table Description.

Table `people`:

```
id   | name  |
--------------
01   | john  |
02   | alex  |
```

Table `job`:

```
id   | job       | date start  |
---------------------------------
01   | student   | 1/1/2013    |
01   | employee  | 1/1/2014    |
01   | manager   | 3/18/2014   |
02   | student   | 3/1/2013    |
02   | engineer  | 3/3/2014    |
```

I need the result showed 1 row for each id.

Here is my SQL query :

```
select id,name,job,date_start
from people,job
group by date_start,id,name,job
```

I got wrong result from that query. I don't know how to show just only 1 record for each id.

Here is the result I want :

Query result

```
id | name | job     | date_start |
----------------------------------
01 | john | manager | 3/18/2014  |    -> max date from id='01'
02 | alex | engineer| 3/3/2014   |    -> max date from id='02'
```

It's ordered by date and selected only 1 result from each id with the max date.

How can I do this ?

Comment: did you check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this**

```
WITH j AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id  ORDER BY date_Start DESC) AS RowNumber,
        id, job, date_start
    FROM job
)
select  p.id, p.name, j.job, j.date_start
from    people p
        inner join j
            on p.id = j.id
            and j.RowNumber = 1
```

As you requested..

- OVER is just like a grouping and sorting area in your select query but it only uses by a functions like ROW_Number()/RANK()/DENSE_RANK()/NTILE(n) and the like. [see here for more info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
- PARTITION BY is like having a group, in my example i partitioned or grouped the rows by id
- ORDER By is like having order by clause in the select query

ROW_Number() is a function in SQL Server that produces a sequence of integer value from 1 to N (up to the last record) and we reset the number generated by ROW_Number() function each time the PARTITION BY area changes its values.

Comment: that's working too.. but i don't know about 'over partition'. could you explain it for me?

Comment: wow. thank you so much. i think i need time to understand it, but it looks more efficent. so that ordered record by date_start, give it a rank and joined it to people table which rank is 1? wow i think this is the best answer

Comment: @RezaKahfi, Yes, its quite complex at first but it is more flexible and perhaps neater in the long run. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT S.id,s.name,S.job,s.date_start
FROM
(
  SELECT T2.id,T1.Name,T2.job,T2.date_start
  from people T1 Left Join job T2 ON T1.id =T2.id
  group by T2.date_start,T2.id,T1.name,T2.job
) AS S Inner JOIN 
( 
  SELECT Max(date_start) AS date_start,id From job 
  Group by id
) AS T ON S.date_start = T.date_start
Order By S.ID
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/652ea/2)

**Output** :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select id_s,job,date_s,name 
from (select id as id_s, max(date_start) as date_s from job group by id),job j,people p
where id_s=j.id and id_s=p.id and date_s=j.date_start;
```

Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: got error message : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
i think it's from ',' before job.

Comment: Try this..
The above query will work for Oracle and this one for SQL :)          

"select t.id_s,job,t.date_s,name 
from (select id as id_s, max(date_start) as date_s from job group by id) as t,job j,people p
where t.id_s=j.id and t.id_s=p.id and t.date_s=j.date_start;"

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `GROUP BY` for this.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, j.job, MAX(j.date_start)
FROM people p
    INNER JOIN job j
        ON p.id= j.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, j.job
```

Comment: Come to think of it, this might not work. Hmmmm...I might delete this.

Comment: You cannot group by `j.job`

Comment: Yea, I'm thinking that's where it'll break.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
select p.id,p.name,j.job,j.date_start
from people p left join job j on p.id=j.id
group by p.id order by max(j.date_start) desc;
```

Hope it will  help you.

Comment: it's not work. got an error message, Column 'people.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: look like it must group by all the other column. and if i do that, the result will be same

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This

```
 Select id,name,job,date_start from pepople p,job j,(select id,max(date_start) 
 as maxdate from job) as tbl where p.id=j.id and j.id=tbl.id and 
 j.date_start=tbl.maxdate
```

Comment: it need to be grouped by, and has ambiguous field. sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
select j.id,name,(Select k.job from job k where k.date_start=
max(j.date_start) and k.id=j.id ) as 'job', max(j.date_start) as 'date_start'
from people p inner join job j on j.id=p.id group by p.name,p.id
having max(j.date_start) order by j.id
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, j.job, j.dateStart
FROM tbl_people p
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT a.id, b.job, a.dateStart
 FROM (
 SELECT id, MAX(date_start) as dateStart
 FROM tbl_job
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY MAX(date_start) DESC
) A
INNER JOIN tbl_job B
ON A.id = B.id and A.dateStart = B.date_start
) j
ON p.id = j.id
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a087/13)

Comment: nearly, but i need only one record for each id. your sql showed all the record and ordered it, but i just need one record for each id

Comment: Try the 2nd one @RezaKahfi

Comment: same result like the first.. it's showing all record, however i need just one result for each id.

Comment: got an error : The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
do you know why?